# Get a random number between 65 and 90

Tags: delphi

I need to get a random number between 65 and 90. I tried by saying `random(65, 90)` but it says I have too many actual parameters.

```pascal
procedure TfrmWordGame.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  randomNumber : integer;
begin
  randomNumber := random(65, 90);
end;

end.
```

Also, I tried by saying `randomRange(65, 90)`

Comment: Perhaps the OP is using an old Delphi version without the `RandomRange` function. If so, the OP can use `65 + (90 - 65) *  Random`. Round to an integer if you want that. It is trivial to mentally visualise the correctness of this approach. (If not, use pen and pencil.)

Comment: @Andreas best not introduce floating point here

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Correct. I don't have access to any Delphi right now, but even old Delphi RTLs do have a `Random(Int)` overload (which isn't implemented using the floating-point `Random`), don't they? (But the OP's "a random number between 65 and 90" doesn't say anything about integers, so maybe a real number is what (s)he is looking for. The non-compiling pseudocode suggests an `Integer` is wanted, though.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using this homemade function for years:

```
FUNCTION RND(MIN,MAX : INTEGER) : INTEGER; INLINE;
  BEGIN
    Result:=RANDOM(SUCC(MAX-MIN))+MIN
  END;
```

An alternative (using [System.Math.RandomRange](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Math.RandomRange) available in modern Delphis) is:

```
FUNCTION RND(MIN,MAX : INTEGER) : INTEGER; INLINE;
  BEGIN
    Result:=RandomRange(MIN,SUCC(MAX))
  END;
```

Comment: One possible downside with such a personal library function is the potential for confusion regarding `RND(A, B)` vs. `RandomRange(A, B) = RND(A, B - 1)`. But if you mostly need an inclusive endpoint and you know what you are doing, of course you should use such a function! (Might be a good idea to include some very clear XML documentation, though.)

Comment: I made this function way back pre-Delphi, so there was no RandomRange available :-). Also, in my opinion, RandomRange is wrongly implemented - it should be with both parameters inclusive, like my RND. That's what one would expect from a parameter set called "From" and "To" (that they're both inclusive). At least, I would...

Comment: Any way, my parameter names clearly suggest that the values are inclusive...

Comment: @HearthWare: I am inclined to agree: It is nice with an inclusive endpoint for a ranged random integer function. But I am not quite sure about it. The RTL's choice of having a non-inclusive endpoint has the very nice consequence that the image of `RandomRange(A, B)` is a set of size `B - A` (assuming `B > A`).

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: I visualize my function to return [A;B], or [A..B] in Pascal (a closed range) and not [A;B[ (an open-ended range, like RandomRange). You can't even express [A;B[ in Pascal without a "-1" in there... To me, that's logical - not something with "B-A" in it :-).